# String is in wrong format c#

Tags: c#

I'm trying to figure out why when I run my program and press the submit button I get an error saying that my list is in the wrong format. A little background on the program: It's for my visual programming class. The program is for a bank account. I tried to comment on what each section is to make it kinda easier to read

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    //Tab 1 Create and close account
    private void Submitbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double x;

        if (OpenRdo.Checked == true && Nametxtbx.TextLength > 0)
        {
            double.TryParse(Nametxtbx.Text, out x);

            // after clicking the button there is
            // no number; it says system.random
            Random acct = new Random();                
            int AccountNumber = acct.Next(5, 1000);
            outputlbl.Text = acct.ToString();
        }

        // list for accounts 
        // This is where it says I have the error
        // that my list is in the wrong format
        var accounts = new List<Account>
        {
            new  Account(Nametxtbx.Text, double.Parse(outputlbl.Text), 0)
        };

        // Write these records to a file
        WriteFile(accounts);

        // message box when you create account
        if (ValidateChildren(ValidationConstraints.Enabled))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Account Created", "Message", 
                MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }
    }

    //writing to the file
    static void WriteFile(List<Account> accts)
    {
        StreamWriter outputFile = File.CreateText("accounts.txt");
        string record;

        foreach (var acct in accts)
        {
            record = $"{acct.Name},{acct.Balance}";
            Console.WriteLine($"Writing record: {record}");
            outputFile.WriteLine(record);
        }

        outputFile.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Usually that exception means exactly what it says: According to the used Culture (by default retreived from Windows) this is not a valid double.

Comment: (A) Pay attention to what the error message says (it is English, you should be able to understand it). (B) Pay attention to which method call at which code line produces the error. (C) You now have the knowledge to fix your problem. (D) Profit! ;)

Comment: See if you can now reduce your large reproducer to a program of one to three lines. That will be a lot easier to understand and diagnose than the code you posted, 95% of which is completely irrelevant to your question.

Comment: @elgonzo: Well, it also requires knowing that your cultures way to write numbers is not the only way to write numbers. A lot of english speakers oddly do not get that until they run into this exception.

Comment: Is this line correct (is `Nametxtbx` supposed to contain a double?):  `double.TryParse(Nametxtbx.Text, out x);` Also, `TryParse` calls are normally part of an `if` condition (where the `else` would be to display some message to the user that they need to enter a valid number). Additionaly, you never use the variable `x` after this method, so what's it's purpose?

Comment: @Christopher, isn't double.Parse(string) supposed to use the "current culture" (i.e., the language/region settings as used by the host OS)?

Comment: @elgonzo: Wich is a problem if the string was created in another culture. Last I looked England and the USA write their dates and numbers pretty much opposite.

Comment: @Christopher, the string comes from a control of the UI of the program that runs on the host OS. Chances are pretty high that the user is used (ahem) to the regional settings of their own computer...

Comment: @elgonzo: It is copied and pasted from somepalce else like a webpage? It is only put there temporarily for testing purpsoes, it actualyl comes from a CSV file created in anotehr culture?

Comment: @Christopher, the value of `outputlbl.Text` doesn't look like "coming from some file" or "copy&pasted from a webpage"...

Comment: @elgonzo: "Output Label". That does not sound like soemthing that comes from the user at all. It sounds like soemthing that comes from other code. Like a output for testing purposes. Also I have ran into those issues often enough to **know** they happen. They just do. Murphys law and all that. There is nothing to argue about here. It either is the case. Or it is not. And only one person can test that.

Comment: @Christopher, stuff happens. Nobody argues that. But we are at this question here. You make assumptions about where the value of `outputlbl.Text` comes that are not supported by the code snippet in the question. Rather contrary to your assumptions, the code very clearly shows the value of `outputlbl.Text` being programmatically assigned from a object "name" string ((which quite certainly is related to the problem), albeit this being gated by an `if` statement

Comment: If the label says "system.random" how is that going to become a double?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell (this is rather a lot of code), the issues are those lines:

```
Random acct = new Random();                
int AccountNumber = acct.Next(5, 1000);
outputlbl.Text = acct.ToString();
```

You set the label to "System.Random" (because you call ToString() on the wrong thing). And that can not be sensibly casted into a integer later.

Ideally you should not even retrieve the data from the UI. If you got a integer in code behind, keep it there. Use it. But with the seperation between Events that might not be always possible.

Comment: Just as an additional comment, You should not be creating a new `Random()` object each time the button is pressed. You should only have one instance created one time in your entire program, like a singleton.

Comment: @Icemanind: Oh right, that too. With button it will not be as huge of a problem, but generally due to how they are initialized if you create a lot of Randoms in the same millisecond and give the same "next" order, they will all return the same value. It is better to keep a few random instances arround.

Comment: @Icemanind If you use a single random through the entire program you will need that handle thread safety also.

Comment: @Magnus with Random quick creation of Random instances has historically caused way more issues.  But agreed, this is an issue as you should only have one instance but also need to use it Threadsavely: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random?view=netframework-4.7.2#avoiding-multiple-instantiations

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend, do not just parse a text if you not know whats in the textbox.
Rather do something like this

```
if(double.TryParse (outputlbl.Text, out double outputNumber))
{
     new  Account(Nametxtbx.Text, outputNumber, 0);
}
```

Also, have a look at the [formatprovider](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.iformatprovider?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: TryParse is primarily there to get around the Vexing exceptions. He still needs to understand why that exception happens and how to avoid it. Otherwise he will jsut get unexplained 0 returns. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions/

Comment: That is totally true. But in my opinion TryParse is easier to debug and understand specially for beginners. The conversation error is a good hint for a wrong format provider.